# Why are my margins so messed up?

Tags: html, css

There is an odd problem here that I don't really understand.

I'm trying to just make the middle of the 3 vertical divs have another div inside it which has a black border and 10px of margin on all sides.

However, on the right side there is no visible margin, and on the bottom the div flows right out of the parent div and out of site into the footer.

What am I doing wrong? CSS for the middle div pair...

```
 #mainContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#platter {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7wuty0/1/

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to use is `padding` on the parent div instead of setting a margin the child which would break the layout http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7wuty0/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/efordek0/1/

Borders are applied outside of the element, therefore if your element is `width:100%;` with a `border: 1px solid black;`, the border will fall outside of your desired constraint.

Instead of applying a margin to the inner-div `#platter`, apply a padding to the outer div `#mainContent`. This way the `100%` values will still apply but be subtracted by the 10px padding of the `#mainContent` and your borders remain inside the desired area.

Comment: that works, you're right. One thing that still confuses me though is why I have to take `width: 100%` off of the `#mainContent` div....if I leave it on, it goes off-screen to the right. Isn't that MORE than 100%? See what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7wuty0/5/

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, btw!

Comment: Hi, and thank you! Excited to be here :)

I'm not certain however I suspect that when you write `width:100%` the size of your object becomes equivalent to the size of your view-port/browser. This size does not take into account the pixel allocation for the vertical scroll bar on the right. Thus you get an overflow exactly the same size as that of the scroll-bar. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct solution : http://jsfiddle.net/5L4tnwtg/

The changes:
Add:

```
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Modify:

```
#mainContent {
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   padding: 10px;
}

#platter {
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: (You forgot to save the fiddle I think)